# Focus on next field when pressing enter React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to find a way to focus on the next field when I click enter in the input using React.js

```
  @autobind
  handleKeyPress(event){
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
      this.refs.email.focus();
    }
  }

  @autobind
  handleKeyPressEmail(event){
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
      this.refs.zip_code.focus();
    }
  }

        <input
          onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
          ref = 'name'
        />

        <input
          onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPressEmail}
          ref = 'email'
        />

        <input
          ref = 'zip_code'
        />
```

This is the best way I have found so far, however I don't want to repeat myself by creating a function everytime I want that to happen. Is there a better and cleaner way to implement this?

Answer (score 33):

If `<form>` is present:

```js
function handleEnter(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    const form = event.target.form;
    const index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(form, event.target);
    form.elements[index + 1].focus();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
...
<form>
  <input onKeyDown={handleEnter} />
  <input onKeyDown={handleEnter} />
  <input />
</form>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/vitalyq/pen/oBvxJB?editors=0010)

Without `<form>`:

```js
function useFocusNext() {
  const controls = useRef([]);

  const handler = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      // Required if the controls can be reordered
      controls.current = controls.current
        .filter((control) => document.body.contains(control))
        .sort((a, b) =>
          a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING
            ? -1 : 1
        );

      const index = controls.current.indexOf(event.target);
      const next = controls.current[index + 1];
      next && next.focus();

      // IE 9, 10
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  return useCallback((element) => {
    if (element && !controls.current.includes(element)) {
      controls.current.push(element);
      element.addEventListener('keydown', handler);
    }
  }, []);
};

...
const focusNextRef = useFocusNext();

<input ref={focusNextRef} />
<input ref={focusNextRef} />
<button ref={focusNextRef}>Submit</button>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/vitalyq/pen/GRNXmQY?editors=0011)

Comment: Hi Vitaly, thank you for your advice! But for me it worked only if I use event.charCode instead of event.keyCode.

Comment: my last component on my page _a multiple step form with several component to compose the final form_ is a [react-maskedinput](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-maskedinput)'s element. On this react-maskedinput's element, I would do a check like: `if(!form.elements || !form.elements[index + 1]) return alert("last input on page")`. On running my webapplication, my console returns me the following error: `Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: "children is undefined"`, do you know why?

Comment: @max: it should work in IE9+, what's your browser, OS version, keyboard layout and input language?

Comment: @Webwoman: please create a new question and attach a code sample reproducing the issue.

Comment: Yeah, but this means that my inputs are inside a form, which is not always true

Comment: @georgekrax: I have updated the answer, please, check it out.

Comment: @VitalyKuznetsov: Okay, but after getting some experience on it, I have been using `refs`, which are also the official and recommended way to manipulate DOM elements with JavaScript in React.

Answer (score 9):

You can use componentDidMount and auto bind refs through a for-in loop.

http://codepen.io/jzmmm/pen/PzZgRX?editors=0010

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._handleKeyPress = this._handleKeyPress.bind(this);
  }

  // Loop through the ref's object, and bind each of them to onkeypress
  componentDidMount() {
    for (let x in this.refs) {
      this.refs[x].onkeypress = (e) => 
        this._handleKeyPress(e, this.refs[x]);
    }
  }

  // This checks ENTER key (13), then checks if next node is an INPUT
  // Then focuses next input box
  _handleKeyPress(e, field) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission if button present
      let next = this.refs[field.name].nextSibling;

      if (next && next.tagName === "INPUT") {
        this.refs[field.name].nextSibling.focus();
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="name" ref='name' />
          <input type="text" name="email" ref='email' />
          <input type="text" name="zip_code" ref='zip_code' />
        </form>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to make it simpler:

```
  @autobind
  handleKeyPress(value, event){
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
      this.refs[event].focus();
    }
  }

    <input
      onKeyPress={(event) => this.handleKeyPress('email', event)}
      ref = 'name'
    />

    <input
      onKeyPress={(event) => this.handleKeyPress('zip_code', event)}
      ref = 'email'
    />

    <input
      ref = 'zip_code'
    />
```

Comment: This can be improved with @autobind removed and currying with partial bind. I.e. `onKeyPress={ this.handleKeyPress.bind(this, 'email') }`. But this is available only with `Function.prototype.bind` polyfill or with 'newer' browsers (aka. non old ie).

Comment: see my answer for another solution

Answer (score 1):

Without `<form>` and TypeScript version.
Skip disabled inputs.

```js
const onKeyPress: React.KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = useCallback(
  (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      const inputs = Array.from(
        // Get table or tbody whatever that contains all inputs. The number of parentElements depends on the structure of your html
        e.currentTarget?.parentElement?.parentElement?.parentElement?.querySelectorAll(
          "input"
        ) ?? []
      ).filter((e) => !e.disabled)
      const index = inputs.indexOf(e.currentTarget)
      inputs[index + 1]?.focus()
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  },
  []
)

return <input type="number" onKeyPress={onKeyPress} />
```