# React Passing focus on next input box after writing one number in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey guys i was rendering four input boxes in my OTP component of my app now what i want is after writing one number in my first input box i want my focus shifted to second input box as the second digit of the otp will be written in second input box.

Similarily for the third and fourth box and updating state at each time the number is written in input box so that i can send back the opt of 4 digit to server to verify it
.I am using class based component.

```
<div className="input_boxes">
              <input type="number" className="otp_box"/>
              <input type="number" className="otp_box"/>
              <input type="number" className="otp_box"/>
              <input type="number" className="otp_box"/>
              </div>
```

Comment: Look into `useRef` and `ref.current.focus()`

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577224/focus-on-next-field-when-pressing-enter-react-js, but instead of checking key code, check the value of the input that triggered the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

**Update :**

Every digi input is limited as single digi.

You could try the code below :

```js
// Example class component
class Thingy extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        focusIndex:null,
        firstDigi:null,
        secondDigi:null,
        thirdDigi:null,
        fourthDigi:null
    };
   this.ref0 = React.createRef()
   this.ref1 = React.createRef()
   this.ref2 = React.createRef()
   this.ref3 = React.createRef()
  }
  
  
  componentDidMount() {
     this.focusDiv();
  }
  
 componentDidUpdate() {
    this.focusDiv();
  }

  
  
  storeDigi=(e,index)=>{
      let valueToken = e.target.value
      if(e.target.value > 10)
      {
          valueToken = e.target.value % 10
      }
  
      switch(index)
          {
             case 1:
              this.setState({
                  focusIndex:2,
                  firstDigi:valueToken
              })
              break;
             case 2:
              this.setState({
                  focusIndex:3,
                  secondDigi:valueToken
              })
              break;
             case 3:
              this.setState({
                  focusIndex:4,
                  thirdDigi:valueToken
              })
              break;
             case 4:
              this.setState({
                  focusIndex:1,
                  fourthDigi:valueToken
              })
              break;   
          }
      
  }
  
  focusDiv=()=>{
      if(this.state.focusIndex)
      {
          console.log(this.state.focusIndex)
          switch(this.state.focusIndex)
          {
             case 1:
              this.ref0.current.focus()
              break;
             case 2:
              this.ref1.current.focus()
              break;
             case 3:
              this.ref2.current.focus()
              break;
             case 4:
              this.ref3.current.focus()
              break;    
          }
      }
  }
  
  getNumber=()=>{
     return Number(this.state.firstDigi*1000+this.state.secondDigi*100+this.state.thirdDigi*10+this.state.fourthDigi*1)
  }
  
   

  render() {
   
    return (
      <div>    
          <div style={{display:"flex"}}>
              <input type="number"  value={this.state.firstDigi} min="0" max="9" onChange={(e)=>this.storeDigi(e,1)} ref={this.ref0}/>
              <input type="number"  value={this.state.secondDigi} min="0" max="9" onChange={(e)=>this.storeDigi(e,2)} ref={this.ref1}/>
              <input type="number"  value={this.state.thirdDigi} min="0" max="9" onChange={(e)=>this.storeDigi(e,3)} ref={this.ref2}/>
              <input type="number"  value={this.state.fourthDigi} min="0" max="9" onChange={(e)=>this.storeDigi(e,4)} ref={this.ref3}/>
          </div>
          <div>{"Number : "+this.getNumber()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy title="I'm the thingy" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

[image]